# Spring Boot JSP Jar Packaging issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was trying to package Spring Boot MVC application which uses JSP as a JAR with embedded Tomcat container but came across [Spring Boot JSP limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). Still I found that placing JSPs inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views/` works while running in eclipse. But when I make JAR out of it and run it using `java -jar` command, it stops working and give `whitelabel` error page (using Spring Boot `1.5.4.RELEASE`).

I followed tutorial at [Serving JSPs with Jar Packaging](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic/) and was able to package the project as JAR and successfully run with `java -jar` command. But this project uses Spring Boot `1.4.2.RELEASE`. When I upgraded it to `1.5.4.RELEASE`, it stopped working.

Can anybody explain why upgrading Spring Boot version does not allow me to package JSPs inside a JAR? Is there any workaround?

Comment: It shouldn't have worked from the beginning and isn't supposed to work. Spring Boot uses quite a few custom resource loaders especially when running as a packaged jar. I strongly suggest to abandon this pursuit and either use a war instead of a jar (which can be executable as well) or use a different view technology (which would be more advisable) like Thymeleaf.

Comment: You should place your JSP files under /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ like you normally would + in order to avoid the limitation, don't use embedded Tomcat, use the unembedded one.

Comment: @M. Deinum I know it shouldn't have, I don't know how, but it does work. You can download the source code from the link to confirm it.  Nevertheless, could you guide me how to make/run executable war?

Comment: just switch packaging from `jar` to `war`.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks. That was easy. I thought `war` wouldn't work with `java -jar`.